# New to Spark and Spark SQL with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-migration, bigdata

I am new to Spark and Spark SQL but know Java and SQL.

How can I use Spark SQL specifically to get a set of Oracle stored procedures converted to Spark using Spark SQL. Examples please.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is example Spark SQL ; Can you ask me

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SparkSQL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> peopleDS = sparkSession.read().json("C:\\people.json");
        peopleDS.createOrReplaceTempView("people");

        Dataset<Row> sql = sparkSession.sql("select city,avg(age) from people group by city");

        sql.show();



    }

}
```